# how to do getpwnam/getpwuid etc in tcl

Tags: tcl, getpwnam

does tcl have a standard way of doing NSS lookups (getpwnam, setpwent,...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tcl doesn't expose those as APIs (it doesn't really use them internally either) but the [TclX](http://tclx.sourceforge.net/) extension package *does* support [exactly what you want](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2009) I believe. For example:

```
package require TclX

set uid [id convert user $tcl_platform(user)]
puts "Your userid is $uid and you are a member of these groups: [id groups]"
```

If you're using ActiveTcl, you've definitely got the TclX package available (either already installed or available from the teapot repository).